# Unit testing Express / Loopback middleware without starting a server

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs

Is there a way to unit test Express / Loopback middleware without actually creating a server and listening on a port?

The problem I have is that creating multiple servers in my test code will introduce the problem of port conflicts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) module.

> You may pass an http.Server, or a Function to request() - if the server is not already listening for connections then it is bound to an ephemeral port for you so there is no need to keep track of ports.

## Mocha

An example with mocha

```
var request = require('supertest');
var app = require('path/to/server.js');

describe('GET /user', function() {
  it('respond with json', function(done) {
    request(app)
      .get('/user')
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .expect(200, done);
  });
});
```

## Ava

Also, you might be interested in the [ava](https://github.com/avajs/ava) test runner instead of mocha.

**Main reason** : [process isolation between test files](https://github.com/avajs/ava#process-isolation)

This is usually my test file template with ava

```
var describe = require('ava-spec').describe;
var app = require('path/to/server.js');
var request = require('supertest');

describe("REST API", function(it){
  it.before.cb(function(t){
    request(app)
      .post('/api/Clients/')
      .send({
        "username": "foo",
        "password": "bar"
      })
      .expect(200, function(err, res){
          t.end(err);
      });
  });

  it.serial.cb('Does something',
  function(t){
    request(app)
      .get(//..)
      .expect(404, function(err, res){
        if (err) return t.end(err);
        t.end();
      });
  });
  it.serial.cb('Does something else afterward',
  function(t){
    request(app)
      .get(//..)
      .expect(401, function(err, res){
        if (err) return t.end(err);
        t.end();
      });
  });
});
```

The `serial` identifier tells ava to run the `it` clause serially. Otherwise it will run all tests from all files in parallel.

Thanks to process isolation, each test file gets its own, isolated loopback instance (and node environment in general), and all test files can be run in parallel, which speeds up tests as well. Inside each test file however, using `serial`, tests will run one after another, in the order they are written in the file.

Comment: thanks - never liked Supertest but maybe I will give it another shot! Also AVA is cool but it's not that cool. I am working on http://github.com/oresoftware/suman which will eventually give AVA a serious run for its money.

Comment: Well supertest gets the job done, and I like it personnally. Coming from mocha, I find ava more verbose, but the process isolation is just too good to go back. Good luck on this project, it's quite ambitious work. By the way, AVA does not enforce an assertion library afaik.

Comment: BTW, does this answers your question ?

Comment: probably the best answer but I will see if there are some other options too

Comment: I remember people from strongloop initally wrote a test system for loopback, but eventually they deprecated it in favor of supertest. I'll try to find the link.

Comment: AVA does not trap errors well, so using their built-in assertion library is much better for that, but then you end up having to use theirs.